# After installing ubuntu 16.04 from windows 7, my laptops hard drive is running almoust 100%

Tags: 16.04, hard-drive, cpu, cpu-load

I'm new guy with Ubuntu. I used Windows OS for more then 15 years, but now I decided to change OS, want to use open source OS and in studies I had opportunity to touch Linux OS, it was hard but as I see now it's interesting and challenging for me. I'm trying to create my personal programming environment in Linux Ubuntu 16.04. I have managed to learn in couple weeks how to manage a little bit Ubuntu OS. But I have problem, a big problem that I didn't noticed from the start when I installed Linux Ubuntu 16.04 OS x64.

**I installed like this:** Formatted C disk of windows, but left D disk with all my personal data, files and other information. On the moment of partition creation, the D disk I changed to NTFS I guess, and after that I installed Linux Ubuntu 16.04. From the beginning of using Linux OS I experienced that my 4 CPU is running almost all the time at 100% even if I use only chrome browser, `xampp` and sublime text 3. My hard drive is running very loudly (in windows 7 I didn't had this problem with CPU's and hard drive it was running smooth and not loud).

Is there any way to fix this problem? I was trying to search for answer but what I found was the way how to reduce swap from 60 to 10 and how to see how my PC is in use. My laptop is Dell laptop Vostro it's not new laptop, but before Linux install it was running smooth. Please help me how I could fix this problem of mine.

Comment: Can you add more information about you laptop specification?

Comment: Hi, i3, 4GB ram, 2.13Ghz, 500GB hard drive.

Comment: Please add the output of the command `free -h` into your question. Regarding the disk usage, `df -h` could help, too.

Comment: In evening I will post it, becouse I'm not at home and I'm without my PC. But how it could help?

Comment: Please look at `top`also .. it provide information which processes are using cpu- and other resources. Update your question with this.

Comment: Well when I turn everything off, like no apps are running, only OS, my hard drive is spining like crazy and as I was researching for help, i found that when all my aps are down only OS is up, my cpu is ~50% usage, in terminal process usage I see 1-10% ussage from apps... and memory usage is about ~2gb out of 3.4

Comment: file:///home/willowdodger/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202017-02-22%2019-30-23.png